# How to solve this hyperbolic problem?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given is Question and my approach of Solving problem.
I don't have computer to type in text format so I'm attaching a Images Please don't down vote it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

Use the asymptotes as (oblique) coordinate axes. The equation of the hyperbola is then $xy=c^2$, where $c^2=(a^2+b^2)/2=61/2$. It is then easy to prove that:
$$
y_L=y_P+y_Q=2y_R,
$$
that is (if $P$ and $Q$ are on the same branch):
$$
LO=PM+QN=2RE,
$$
where $O$ is the origin.